# How to add custom object for workday API for Edit_Worker_additional_Data

Tags: api, workday-api

SOAP based XML file :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:cus="urn:com.workday/tenants/super/data/custom">
<soapenv:Header>
<bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
<bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>1</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
</bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<bsvc:Edit_Worker_Additional_Data_Request bsvc:version="v36.0">
<bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
<bsvc:Auto_Complete>true</bsvc:Auto_Complete>
<bsvc:Run_Now>true</bsvc:Run_Now>>
<bsvc:Comment_Data>
<bsvc:Comment>Test comment on 27 March- attempt2</bsvc:Comment>
</bsvc:Comment_Data>
</bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
<bsvc:Worker_Custom_Object_Data>
<bsvc:Effective_Date>2021-03-25</bsvc:Effective_Date>
<bsvc:Worker_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="Employee_ID">
<bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Employee_ID">123</bsvc:ID>
</bsvc:Worker_Reference>
<bsvc:Business_Object_Additional_Data>
<cus:ContractData>
<cus:contractDate>2021-03-23</cus:contractDate>
<cus:wd002AddendumEffectiveDate2>2021-05-23</cus:wd002AddendumEffectiveDate2>
<cus:commissionRates>22.25</cus:commissionRates>
</cus:ContractData>
</bsvc:Business_Object_Additional_Data>
</bsvc:Worker_Custom_Object_Data>
</bsvc:Edit_Worker_Additional_Data_Request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

C# code:

```
 `ServiceReference1.Edit_Worker_Additional_DataInput data = new ServiceReference1.Edit_Worker_Additional_DataInput();    data.Edit_Worker_Additional_Data_Request.Worker_Custom_Object_Data.Business_Object_Additional_Data.Any=
```

new System.Xml.XmlElement[] { };`

How to store soap xml file data in "System.Xml.XmlElement[]" array ?